# Mac Automator using excel data to webpage

Tags: automator

At work, I have to fill in many numbers on a daily bases.  Most of them are redundant and are the same each day.  But one column changes each day.

[Webpage screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed8SM.png)

The first column is the one that always changes, the second is always left blank, and the third and fourth are always zeros.

I have done a script for the third and fourth columns.

```
delay 3.0
    keystroke tab
    delay 0.2

    repeat 5 times
        keystroke tab
        delay 0.2
        keystroke tab
        delay 0.2
        keystroke "0"
        delay 0.2
        keystroke tab
        delay 0.2
        keystroke "0"
        delay 0.2
        keystroke tab

    end repeat



    keystroke "6" -- This is for 6-lb-0-0 for Pepperoni
    delay 0.2
    keystroke tab
    delay 0.2

    delay 0.2
    keystroke tab
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "0"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke tab
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "0"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke tab

    repeat 2 times
        keystroke tab
        delay 0.2
        keystroke tab
        delay 0.2
        keystroke "0"
        delay 0.2
        keystroke tab
        delay 0.2
        keystroke "0"
        delay 0.2
        keystroke tab

    end repeat

    keystroke "6" -- This is for 6-lb-0-0 for Sausage
    delay 0.2
    keystroke tab
    delay 0.2

    delay 0.2
    keystroke tab
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "0"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke tab
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "0"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke tab

    repeat 3 times
        keystroke tab
        delay 0.2
        keystroke tab
        delay 0.2
        keystroke "0"
        delay 0.2
        keystroke tab
        delay 0.2
        keystroke "0"
        delay 0.2
        keystroke tab

    end repeat

    keystroke tab -- This is for LB - LB - 0 - 0 For the last item in     on the list.
    delay 0.2
    keystroke tab
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "0"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke tab
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "0"
    delay 0.2
```

I know I can just use brute force and make 7 different days of this.  But I figured I could use something like excel to copy and paste or use variables in Automator?  I have searched online and everything that I can find and understand talks about going from a site to excel, and not excel to a site.

Any suggestions on how to make this easier?

Thanks
Chip